# How to group across 2nd level relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by, rails-activerecord

If database structure is the following:

```
Projects
Features
- ProjectId FK
Tasks
- FeatureId FK
- Estimate
```

And models are the following:

```
Project has_many features
Feature has_many tasks, belongs_to project
Task belongs_to feature
```

How do I get a list of tasks for specific project grouped by `FeatureId` with `sum(Estimate)` using ActiveRecord query interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it this way

```
project = Project.first

Task.where(feature_id: project.features)
    .select("feature_id, sum(estimate)")
    .group("feature_id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a Project object, try

```
Task.joins(:feature => :project).where(:projects => {:id => project.id}).group("features.id").sum(:estimate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this

```
Project.joins(:features => :tasks).group("features.id")
 .where("projects.id = ?", project_id).select("tasks.id, SUM(estimate)")
```